# iPhone: Lock the UITableView and ControllerView

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have been using UITableView and UIController in every screen of my application. It is simple game application where I have every screen full of particular image at particular stage and hot area to enable the object selection. The most annoying part is even entire View has fill up with image, I am able to drag it up and down which shows me blank screen. I want it to lock it so that nothing should happen when you try to drag it. Could anyone please help me out here.

Thanks.

Comment: In other words, you just want to lock the UITable from dragging right ?

Comment: Yes Legolas. That's correct. Also not just UITable, also for custom UI view controller where I keep adding buttons and labels dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting the `scrollEnabled` property to NO?

You can access it through the `tableView` property of your `UITableViewController`.

Preferred place where you can set it: `-viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Where is that property? I don't see it under self (UIViewController) or self.View.

Comment: Sorry this is a property of `UITableView`, actually inherited from `UIScrollView`, which is the base class. I modified the answer...

Comment: sorry, I am lost... are you using `UITableView` with a "generic" `UIViewController` (i.e., not with `UITableViewController`)? Anyway, what you need is access your `UITableView` and set that property... if you are using a generic `UIViewController` and set its view property so that it is now your UITableView, than, it will work (if you cast the view).

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. Let me make the question simple. How could I make UIViewController.View locked?

To answer your question, I have base class BaseController which implements UIVIewController. All other classes(including TableViewController) inherit this class along with their required delegates. Every class has self.View property. I want to decide lock this view. Thanks.

Comment: You could have a look at `touchesBegan`/`touchesEnd`/`touchesMove`... you can override those methods to enforce that your view cannot be dragged about, but you will need to support tapping, I guess. Also check into the `UIGestureRecognizer` class, which is attachable to a view, so possibly is better for you.

Comment: I researched more on this. Creating UIScrollView object with required properties and assigning it to my UIViewController.View worked fine...! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the coordinates of the touched point as screen coordinates. Then for each frame, compare these against the frame of the view you want the user to remain in.

You can use the function calls below to number crunch this for you:

```
CGRectGetMinX
CGRectGetMaxX
// etc... applies to Y-axis too
```

Check the [CGGeometry](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html)
class reference.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use a `UITableViewController`?
If you do so, there is – `tableView:canMoveRowAtIndexPath`: in the `UITableViewDataSource` Protocol.
Hope this helps...